# Can I define a Map Route from a url to a Controller in a compiler verifiable way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just getting started with MVC.  Watched a few videos, just started a new project.  I see the auto generated MapRoute code from Global.asx:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

Which from my understanding automagically maps requests from "wwww.domain.com/Home/..." to a controller class conventionally named HomeController.  But what if the HomeController class doesn't exist?  Is there another way I can map routes to Controller types that is statically verifiable (i.e. won't compile if I make a fat finger mistake on the name of the controller)?

For example, is there something like this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = typeof(HomeController), action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea. What about an extension method?

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static string GetControllerName(this Controller controller)
    {
        return GetControllerName(controller.GetType());
    }

    public static string GetControllerName(Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType.Name.Substring(0, controllerType.Name.Length - "Controller".Length);
    }
}
```

Then you can use in this way:

```
... new { controller = HomeController.GetControllerName() } ...
```

Comment: yea, something like this is my backup plan. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way. Routes are resolved at runtime. Of course that's why it is a good practice to unit test your route definitions. Personally I use the [MVCContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper#Routes) which I find quite elegant.

Comment: Ack, I think my question was unclear.  I mean if I make a typeo on the Controller name.  For example, what if I did: 'new { controller = "HomeWHOOOPS", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }' on accident.  I would much rather see something like 'new { controller = typeof(HomeController), action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }' as an option.

Comment: @Dejas, if you do this your unit test will blow and you will know that you did something wrong. That's the philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

The following class exists in the open source MvcContrib project (available for download at http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com .

It has an Obsolete attribute, but I don't know why.  I have used it before with no problems.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcContrib.Routing
{
///<summary>
/// Use this class to define url->controller action mappings
///</summary>
[Obsolete]
public class MvcRoute : Route
{
    private MvcRoute(string url)
        : base(url, new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
        Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Fluent interface start method
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="url">The url pattern</param>
    public static MvcRoute MapUrl(string url)
    {
        return new MvcRoute(url);
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Fluent interface start method
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="url">The url pattern</param>
    [Obsolete("Use MapUrl instead")]
    public static MvcRoute MappUrl(string url)
    {
        return new MvcRoute(url);
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Sets the default controller, action and parameters via a lambda method, you can also 
    /// specify additional defaults
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="action">default action</param>
    ///<param name="defaults">other default parameters</param>
    public MvcRoute ToDefaultAction<T>(Expression<Func<T, ActionResult>> action, object defaults) where T : IController
    {
        ToDefaultAction(action);

        foreach(var pair in new RouteValueDictionary(defaults))
        {
            Defaults.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        return this;
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Sets the default controller, action and parameters via a lambda method
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="action"></param>
    public MvcRoute ToDefaultAction<T>(Expression<Func<T, ActionResult>> action) where T : IController
    {
        var body = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;

        if(body == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a method call");
        }

        if(body.Object != action.Parameters[0])
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Method call must target lambda argument");
        }

        string actionName = body.Method.Name;

        // check for ActionName attribute
        var attributes = body.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionNameAttribute), false);
        if(attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            var actionNameAttr = (ActionNameAttribute)attributes[0];
            actionName = actionNameAttr.Name;
        }

        string controllerName = typeof(T).Name;

        if(controllerName.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            controllerName = controllerName.Remove(controllerName.Length - 10, 10);
        }

        Defaults = LinkBuilder.BuildParameterValuesFromExpression(body) ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
        foreach(var pair in Defaults.Where(x => x.Value == null).ToList())
            Defaults.Remove(pair.Key);

        Defaults.Add("controller", controllerName);
        Defaults.Add("action", actionName);

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add constraints to this route
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="constraints">The constraints defined as an anonymous object</param>
    public MvcRoute WithConstraints(object constraints)
    {
        foreach(var pair in new RouteValueDictionary(constraints))
        {
            Constraints.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add defaults to this route, if you use the ToDefaultAction 
    /// method the controller and action default will be overwritten.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="defaults">The defaults defined as an anonymous object</param>
    public MvcRoute WithDefaults(object defaults)
    {
        foreach(var pair in new RouteValueDictionary(defaults))
        {
            Defaults.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        return this;
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Sets the list of namespaces to look for controllers
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="namespaces">An array of namespaces</param>
    public MvcRoute WithNamespaces(string[] namespaces)
    {
        if(namespaces == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("namespaces");
        }

        DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
        DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;

        return this;
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Add this route to the route collection with the specified name
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="routeName">The name of the route</param>
    ///<param name="routes">The route collection to add the route to</param>
    public MvcRoute AddWithName(string routeName, RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(routeName, this);
        return this;
    }
}
 }
```